# Smartphone with maximum screen-to-body ratio

Tags: smartphones

I'm currently looking for a smartphone with maximum screen-to-body ratio. I need the smartphone to look like kind of a futuristic way. like screen on both of the edges or screen covering maximum area on front and less edge borders. It doesn't have to be cheap or powerful in processing etc. I just need it to look like a next-gen gadget. any help is appreciated. thanks in advance!

Comment: It does not look like you are asking for a specific recommendation, and unfortunately we cannot answer this question here. Unless you ask a manufacturer directly, most answers that you will get will be speculation.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is asking for technical details of why something isn't made a certain way.

Comment: I'm clearly asking "if there is any such smartphone available which I'm not aware of please inform me"

Comment: Do you have any other requirements, or is it just the screen ratio has to be 90% or higher?

Comment: No. i just need it to look futuristic. with maximum Screen-to-Body ratio. not specifically 90% or more. but maximum possible to date.

Comment: You should rephrase this question then. The moderators will almost certainly close this question as off-topic.  List a specific set of requirements that you are looking for in the question.  Then ask what phone you should buy with your budget.

Comment: Could you please add what OS you want, color, budget, and storage capacity? I think if you narrow it down, your question will be reopened as on topic.  Having unlimited budget is an acceptable requirement. Also, please try to edit your question to fix some grammatical issues.

Comment: Check [Great screen-to-body ratio phones](http://www.phonearena.com/phones/Display/Great+screen-to-body+ratio)